# Is it possible to find the thumbnail of an existing Imgur image?

Tags: imgur, thumbnail

There's a rather large image in a Stack Overflow post that I'd like to replace with its thumbnail and a link to the full-size image.

I know Imgur generates thumbnails for its images when you upload, but since I'm not the original uploader, is there any way for me to find the thumbnail image by URL hackery or some such?

Comment: Related Meta.SE question: [Thumbnail image on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I can't actually find it documented anywhere, but I uploaded an image and played with the "More Sizes" list:

#### Original

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdJZt.jpg

I haven't included the image inline, because StackExchange would automatically scale it down. To view the original at its full size, click the link.

#### Large thumbnail

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdJZtl.jpg (added an `l` after the image ID)

[image]

#### Small square

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdJZts.jpg (added an `s` after the image ID)

[image]

---

It doesn't always handle transparency well, but "small square" is probably what you want.

<sub>Image by digitalART2, licensed under CC-BY-2.0, available [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/digitalart/1991870530/).</sub>

Comment: Here's the API documentation - the ones listed above are all the available image sizes: http://api.imgur.com/resources_anon#image_hash

Comment: @Ciaran: All the documented ones. There are -h, -m and -b too.

Comment: Updated link to imgur API: http://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs

Answer (score 17):

There are 6 total thumbnails that an image can be resized to. Each one is accessable by appending a single character suffix to the end of the image ID, and before the file extension.

For example, the image located at https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0oPW.gif has the Medium Thumbnail located at [http://i.imgur.com/12345m.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/12345m.jpg)

The thumbnails are:

- s = Small Square (90x90)
- b = Big Square (160x160)
- t = Small Thumbnail (160x160)
- m = Medium Thumbnail (320x320)
- l = Large Thumbnail (640x640)
- h = Huge Thumbnail (1024x1024)

Source: [Imgur API](http://api.imgur.com/models/image).

Comment: The images you linked to are no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone looking for the original link on imgur's API docs

**http://api.imgur.com/models/image**

Comment: This was already linked by DmitrySandalov.